# Cross apply to get a specific record based on DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is the sql fiddle for the following scenario: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/434fc/1

Base table:

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║ Id   DateTime         ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ 201  2015-05-03 08:01 ║
║ 301  2015-05-03 08:20 ║
║ 401  2015-05-03 08:40 ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

Extract Table as E:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║     Id   DateTime            Location ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║     201  2015-05-03 07:50    City A   ║
║     201  2015-05-03 08:01    City B   ║
║     201  2015-05-03 08:50    City C   ║
║     301  2015-05-03 07:15    City E   ║
║     301  2015-05-03 08:01    City F   ║
║     301  2015-05-03 08:20    City G   ║
║     401  2015-05-03 07:15    City W   ║
║     401  2015-05-03 08:30    City X   ║
║     401  2015-05-03 08:55    City Y   ║
║     401  2015-05-03 09:00    City Z   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Desired Result:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║     Location  Id    DateTime         ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║     City B    201   2015-05-03 08:01 ║
║     City G    301   2015-05-03 08:20 ║
║     City X    401   2015-05-03 08:30 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Using the following code, I get the right result for `ID` 201 and 301, but for 401 I need the first largest date in `Extract` table which is less than the date in `Base` table since there is no matching date in `Extract` table as in `Base` table.

```
select ca.Location, B.id, ca.Datetime
from Base B
cross apply(select top 1 Location, DateTime
       from Extract E 
       where B.id = E.id 
       order by case when B.DateTime = E.DateTime then 1 else 0 end desc,
                     E.Datetime)ca
```

Please help in editing this code to get the desired result. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are your columns in a different order between your `select` query, and your *Desired Result?*

Comment: I updated the select statement. The order doesn't matter though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. I adjusted your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/434fc/3/0)

```
select ca.Location, B.id, ca.Datetime
from 
    Base B
    cross apply
    (
        select top (1) E.Location, E.DateTime
        from Extract E 
        where 
            B.id = E.id
            AND B.DateTime >= E.DateTime
        order by E.Datetime DESC
    ) AS CA
```

Please note, that if for a certain ID `Extract` table doesn't have any dates less than or equal to `Base` date, then this ID would not be returned at all. If you do want to see every row from `Base` table no matter what is in `Extract` table, use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`. You'll get NULLs for `Location` and `DateTime`, but all IDs would be there.

Comment: @sky_limit, you are welcome. I made it follow the expected result. Your explanation in the question must have a mistake. My query returns the **largest** (not smallest) date from `Extract` table which is less than or equal to the date in `Base` table.

Comment: You are right. I needed the largest and your code did the trick. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question for future reference. Thanks again.